# How to do sandbox refresh from production

Tags: sandbox-refresh

We have four sandboxes attached to production.If buisness says refresh from prod,what does that means,are they refreshing all code from prod to pfix.How will they do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**How to refresh sandbox:**

1) From Setup, enter Sandboxes in the Quick Find box, then select Sandboxes.
A list of your sandboxes displays. Sandboxes that you can refresh have a Refresh link next to their name.

2) Next to the name, click Refresh.

3) Review the name and description, and edit if necessary.

4) Select the type of sandbox environment you want.

5) Select the data you want to copy.

6) Optionally, check Auto Activate. If you check Auto Activate, your sandbox is activated immediately after you refresh it, and you do not receive an activation email.

7)Click Create.

**Are they refreshing all code from prod ?**
Yes, When you refresh sandbox it refresh all your code base on sandbox. It may also refresh some of the data depending on your type of sandbox and Sandbox Templates.

More info at:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_create.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&language=en_US